# I want to store users passwords in MySQL remote database with PHP, in Android! can anyone help me out?

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, password-protection

I'm starting my first Android project, in which I'm using PHP as a connection to my hosting server, and MySQL database. How and where I should write my code for securing user password(any method)?

Comment: Please take the [tour]. If you Googled this you would find many tutorials and guides regarding this.

Comment: Hi, you need an API and query that API from your Android App.

Answer (score 0):

Send the password plaintext over an encrypted SSL (HTTPS) connection from the Android application to the server, then use the PHP function [password_hash()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to calculate a hash and store this hash in the database. This is the usual workflow, it's the same workflow a web application would use.